# MySQL Workbench stored procedure END with delimiter not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I'm using MariaDB to create a stored procedure using this code:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P1;
DELIMITER // /* Set delimiter */
CREATE PROCEDURE P1(IN `date` DATE, IN `customer` INT, IN `bookingLocation` INT)
BEGIN /* Begin procedure */

/* Declare variables */
DECLARE currDate DATE;
DECLARE customerPlan INT;
DECLARE locCapacity INT;
DECLARE existingBookings INT;
SET currDate=CURRENT_DATE();

IF `date` < currDate THEN /* If date is in past */
    SELECT "DATE CANNOT BE IN PAST" AS error;
ELSE
    SELECT plan INTO customerPlan FROM `customers` WHERE customer_ID = `customer`; /* Get the customer's plan */
    SELECT capacity INTO locCapacity FROM `locations`;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `desk_bookings` WHERE location=bookingLocation;
    
END IF;
END// /* End procedure */
DELIMITER ;
```

The code runs correctly using the command line, but when I run the code in MySQL Workbench, I receive an error:

```
"/" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, '/'
```

Comment: Where do you get this error message? Moreover, this is not a mysql error message.

Comment: The error message is from the MySQL Workbench query editor. Actually running the code returns a normal syntax error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue either locally in workbench or https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=e5330b5b9b1c88173f6cdbc9fe624542

Comment: @P.Salmon your previous comment to remove the SQL comments did work. (Specifically, only when I removed the comment on the `DELIMITER` line).

Comment: And you don't think it would be useful to share the exact syntax error message and which part of the code workbench thinks is incorrect?

Comment: The syntax error message is `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 19
`  although I have already worked out what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by removing the comment on the `DELIMITER // /* Set delimiter */` line.